# Conv2d removing part of the input

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, conv-neural-network

I am writing a program that uses words embeddings and then train it on a simple CNN. The embedding dim is equal to 768 and the hidden dim is equal to 100. I use a PyTorch Conv2d:

After creating embeddings, this is the init() part:

```
self.conv = nn.Conv2d(1, params.hidden_dim, kernel_size=(3, params.embedding_dim))
nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.conv.weight)
nn.init.constant_(self.conv.bias, 0.0)
self.fc = nn.Linear(params.hidden_dim, params.num_of_tags)
```

And this is the forward() part:

```
print(x.shape)   # [4, 39, 768]
x = x.unsqueeze(1)
x = self.conv(x).squeeze(3)
x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
print(x.shape)   # [4, 37, 100]

x = x.contiguous()
x = x.view(-1, x.shape[2])
x = self.dropout(x)
x = self.fc(x)
```

I don't really understand why the shape changes (see the prints). It is the number of words in the sentenced (already padded so in all 4 sentences there is the same number of word).

Does someone know why the the shape changes and what to do to avoid it?

I tried to pad the x in the end but I guess it doesn't make sense because I may lose important input (two removed words). I want the shape to remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a convolution kernel > 1, you "lose" some portion of the signal.
For example, if the kernel size is 3, you need three input features to compute each output feature. In that case, what will happen to the output feature corresponding to the first input feature? This output feature does not have three input feature in its [receptive field](https://blog.mlreview.com/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807).

To maintain the same size output, you need to pad the input. Try:

```py
self.conv = nn.Conv2d(1, params.hidden_dim, kernel_size=(3, params.embedding_dim), padding='same')
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the output layer automatically decreases in effect. This allows to have a better performing model and to avoid overlearning. It also makes it faster and easier to train.
However, if you still want to have the same input and output layers, you can do this:

```py
output_layer = torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)
```

Doing this is not too advisable...